# Lots of graphics issues when trying to start new Electron application

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to build a simple vanilla JS, HTML & CSS application on top of Electron, but I am having trouble starting the application.

I installed Electron using `npm install --save-dev electron`

After that I created a `src` folder and an `index.js` file inside of it. I adjusted the `package.json` file to point into `src` to find `index.js`, but other than that it is pretty boiler plate.

When trying to start electron I receive these messages. [image: [217372:0920/140805.983367:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] Display.cpp:992 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context. [217372:0920/140805.983549:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(831)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context. [217372:0920/140805.983600:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1353)] eglInitialize OpenGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type [217372:0920/140806.018414:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] Display.cpp:992 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context. [217372:0920/140806.018488:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(831)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context. [217372:0920/140806.018520:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1353)] eglInitialize OpenGLES failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED [217372:0920/140806.018548:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(23)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed. [217372:0920/140806.020576:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization [217384:0920/140806.050056:ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported.]

There are no other packages installed. Linux Ubuntu 20.04.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you running this? What graphics drivers do you have installed?

Comment: This might fit better at [SU].

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi; I'll try there. 

What do you mean where? It's out of a project directory out of my general documents folder. If you mean where is the command it's one line up and just `npm start` which runs `electron .`.